# How to Phpunit test a method in an abstract class that uses other methods

Tags: php, phpunit

I have an abstract class as follows:

```
abstract class Entity
{

  public function __construct($configFile, $logger, $database)
  {
    $this->configFile = $configFile;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->database = $database;
  }


  public function SettingData(array $info)
  {
        $this->logger->debug('setting the information'.serialize($info));
        $info = $info.'debug';
        $this->formatData();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the unittest:

```
  $data = array('informations','data');
  $result = Entity::SettingData($data);
  $this->assertTrue($result);
```

I want to test the method SettingData but I get the error:

```
Undefined property: Entity::$logger
```

How Am I supposed to test this method?

Any help is really apreaciated.

Comment: @AlexBlex How can I call the method otherwise? Can't instanciate an abstract class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot test an abstract class.
You have to create a derived class. Then you create an object of that class and call the constructor with testable parameters.
After that you can test SettingData.